# Total filesize recursion

Tags: file, scala, recursion, io

```
def recursiveTotalDirectorySize(dir: File): Long = {
    var totalFileSize = 0L;
    val (dirs, files) = dir.listFiles.partition(_.isDirectory)

    if (dirs.length > 0) dirs.foreach((f: File) => totalFileSize += recursiveTotalDirectorySize(f))

    if (files.length > 0) totalFileSize += files.map((f: File) => f.length()).reduceLeft(_ + _)

    totalFileSize
}
```

Do you have a better solution for total file size recursion using Scala. What are your comments for this. Thanks!

Comment: What are you after? A code review? What do you think would make a better solution?

Comment: Yes something like that, a code review. I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to go for the best practices.

Comment: OK. I posted a different version anyway, but the place for that is probably http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One liner, no mutable vars, parallelizes the processing of each entry in a directory

```
  def recursiveTotalDirectorySize(dir: File): Long =
  dir.listFiles.par.map{
     f => if (f.isDirectory) recursiveTotalDirectorySize(f) else f.length()
  }.sum
```

Comment: Not tail-recursive so it can cause a stackoverflow exception for cyclic links and very large directories.

Comment: Large directories are't a problem (it only recurses for directories, not for each file) - but deep hierarchies might possibly be. But a tail recursive one isn't trivial (you need to track where you are in each subdirectory somehow, so there's state to maintain) and doesn't fix the cyclic link problem either (it just swaps a stack overflow for an infinite loop, without further changes).

Comment: Hat tip to @user3189923 for the hint for parallel execution- four characters (`.par`) makes a very noticeable difference on a big hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

A similar approach, using `foldLeft`,

```
def dirSize(dir: File): Long = 
  ( 0L /: dir.listFiles) { (sum,f) => sum + 
    (if (f.isDirectory) dirSize(f) else f.length) }
```

Accepted answer has the potential quality of using `par.map`; here `par.aggregate` may prove equivalent,

```
def dirSize(dir: File): Long = 
  dir.listFiles.par.aggregate(0L)((sum,f) => sum + 
    (if (f.isDirectory) dirSize(f) else f.length), _+_)
```

In fact `par.aggregate` may be seen as a form of [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).